# Optimize load a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image

Hey guys i have a problem. I have a listview that is dynamically filled. Each row contain images and text, that are retrieved from a web service call ( i get image link in web service call, and I retrieve drawable after the web service call is finished ).

**The question is this:** If I have, let's say 200 images that I have to get, it is faster to pass every link to a thread and download the image in that thread, or should I use only one thread to get all of them? Or, is there any other possibility to obtain that images faster?

Thanks,
Arkde

Comment: You should only get the images that are being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple Threads you reduce the risk of connection timing out causing all of your downloads to be held up. But you certainly don't want 200 threads either.

As was mentioned above, you should try to download images as necessary. I doubt your users are going to view all 200 images everytime they pop into that list.

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is that if I don't have all the images when my list is loaded, if the user scroll down fast, the scrolling will not be smooth at all...

Comment: The scrolling will be smooth if implemented properly. Take a look here at a simple implementation of a listview that downloads images from a URL. [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: IMHO (user perspective) it is better to have a list that can be used immediately but doesn't run smooth instead of waiting ages for a list to load until I can use it even if I only need the first one or two "pages".

Comment: @LazyList: Then may be you should send the code to Google and help them to update the market app to run smooth when showing the "my apps" list and loading the app icons...